# Using SpriteBatch alongside Scene2D to make a nice chatbox (LibGDX)

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx, scene2d, spritebatch

I am currently working on a Java 2D MMORPG using `LibGDX`. I made a chat box completely from scratch using `SpriteBatch` drawing,it includes a text field to enter a new message to chat and a scroll to scroll through the chat. The only problem is that it doesn't look and feel very professional.

What I want to do is use `Scene2D` for the text field and the scroll. Can I use `SpriteBatch` and put `Scene2D` elements on top of it?

Also for the scroll view, I have a custom way of drawing text. I made it so that I can put color codes such as "&y" for example to change the color to yellow. Can I use `SpriteBatch` to draw text into a scroll view using `BitmapFont` and be able to scroll through the it?

Thanks in advance! If you need more info, just ask me!

Comment: Actually, SpriteBatch is used also to draw scene2d stuff, but I think what you're asking is if you can draw with and without scene2d in the same screen, right? You can draw your "regular" stuff, along with `spriteBatch.end`, and then call `stage.draw` to have your scene2d drawn right over everything else. Your second question can surely be done, although I haven't made custom scene2d.ui widgets before, which is what you'll need to do to wrap your special type of text class.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help! I'll look into custom UI. I'll ask if I need help.